# apache-camel 3.4.0 - Error executing command: No matching features for camel-catalog/0

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf-feature

Expected behaviour with camel version 2.15.2/2.24.1

- Below url has feature as "camel-catalog" 
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/2.15.2/apache-camel-2.15.2-features.xml

  <feature name="camel-catalog" version="2.15.2" resolver="(obr)" start-level="50">
  <feature version="2.15.2">camel-core
  mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/camel-karaf-commands-catalog/2.15.2

Exception while deploying feature ="camel-catalog" on Karaf Container with camel 3.x-

karaf@root()> feature:install camel-catalog
Error executing command: No matching features for camel-catalog/0

Query -
Upgraded camel version 3.4.0 now feature ="camel-catalog" is not there and but it require to install in Karaf container So what we can do to resolve this.
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/3.4.0/apache-camel-3.4.0-features.xml

Any help/suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The camel-catalog feature is not available as a feature in Camel 3, you dont need to install it, you get catalog installed via installing camel - `features:install camel`.

See the migration 2.x to 3.x guides: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html